# Call reporting API v4 not permission

Tags: google-api, reporting

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

[image: Permissions have been set]

I hoped successfully called API

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the code (as text) that returns this.  Also, including an image that isn't in English isn't helpful.